# How to remove &#13; or &#xD; in Digital signature using Java

Tags: java, xml, certificate, digital-signature, x509certificate

I created digital signature using java with

```
XMLSignatureFactory xmlSignatureFactory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
```

When whole process completed output xml include `&#13;` in signature
When checking this issue, it happened for line breaks. I removed it using the replace method. But when It check it gives error `Verifying the digest value for the 1. Reference failed`

I tried created signature create using below code

```
private String generateEbXml() throws Exception {
        // Create a DOM XMLSignatureFactory that will be used to generate the enveloped signature.
        XMLSignatureFactory xmlSignatureFactory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

        List<Reference> references = new ArrayList<>();

        DigestMethod digestMethod = xmlSignatureFactory.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null);

        List<Transform> transforms = new LinkedList<>();
        Transform envelopedTransform = xmlSignatureFactory.newTransform(CanonicalizationMethod.ENVELOPED,
                                                                        (TransformParameterSpec) null);
        transforms.add(envelopedTransform);

        String xpathExpr = "not(ancestor-or-self::eb:TraceHeaderList or ancestor-or-self::eb:Via)";

        XPathFilterParameterSpec xpathSpec = new XPathFilterParameterSpec(xpathExpr);

        Transform xpathTransform = xmlSignatureFactory.newTransform(CanonicalizationMethod.XPATH, xpathSpec);
        transforms.add(xpathTransform);

        Transform inclusiveTransform = xmlSignatureFactory.newTransform(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE,
                                                                        (TransformParameterSpec) null);
        transforms.add(inclusiveTransform);

        Reference wholeDocumentReference = xmlSignatureFactory
            .newReference("", digestMethod, transforms, null, null);

        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(resourceFileLocation.concat("ase2.xml"))));

        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        byte[] hash = sha1.digest(content.getBytes());

        Reference aseXmlreference = xmlSignatureFactory
            .newReference("cid:aseXML", digestMethod, null, null, null, hash);

        references.add(wholeDocumentReference);
        references.add(aseXmlreference);

        // Create the SignedInfo
        SignedInfo signedInfo = xmlSignatureFactory
            .newSignedInfo(xmlSignatureFactory
                               .newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE,
                                                          (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
                           xmlSignatureFactory
                               .newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null), references);

        // Load the KeyStore and get the signing key and certificate.
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        //keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("keyStore.p12"), "123456".toCharArray());
        keyStore.load(keyStoreFile.getInputStream(), keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry =
            (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry
                (keyStoreAlias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyStorePassword.toCharArray()));

        X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();

        // Create the KeyInfo containing the X509Data.
        KeyInfoFactory keyInfoFactory = xmlSignatureFactory.getKeyInfoFactory();
        List x509Content = new ArrayList();
        x509Content.add(x509Certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
        x509Content.add(x509Certificate);
        X509Data x509Data = keyInfoFactory.newX509Data(x509Content);

        List<XMLStructure> keyInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();

        KeyValue keyValue = keyInfoFactory.newKeyValue(publicKey);
        keyInfoList.add(keyValue);
        keyInfoList.add(x509Data);

        KeyInfo keyInfo = keyInfoFactory.newKeyInfo(keyInfoList);

        // Instantiate the document to be signed.
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        // process XML securely, avoid attacks like XML External Entities (XXE)
        documentBuilderFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
        documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(resourceFileLocation.concat("ebxml_without_sign_new.xml"));
        Document document = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(resource.getFile());

        // Create a DOMSignContext and specify the RSA PrivateKey and
        // location of the resulting XMLSignature's header element.
        DOMSignContext domSignContext = new DOMSignContext(keyEntry.getPrivateKey(), document.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild());

        // Create the XMLSignature, but don't sign it yet.
        XMLSignature xmlSignature = xmlSignatureFactory.newXMLSignature(signedInfo, keyInfo, null, "WmEbXML-Signature-54cl6h00gi08isbf003ient2", null);

        domSignContext.setURIDereferencer(new EmptyURIDereferencer(document));

        // Marshal, generate, and sign the enveloped signature.
        xmlSignature.sign(domSignContext);

        DOMImplementationLS domImplementationLS = (DOMImplementationLS) document.getImplementation();

        LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplementationLS.createLSSerializer();
        LSOutput lsOutput = domImplementationLS.createLSOutput();
        lsOutput.setEncoding("UTF-8");

        Writer stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        lsOutput.setCharacterStream(stringWriter);
        lsSerializer.write(document, lsOutput);
        String ebxmlContent = stringWriter.toString();

        return ebxmlContent;
    }
```

I tried below code for remove above menction `&#13;`

```
        Field f = XMLUtils.class.getDeclaredField("ignoreLineBreaks");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(null, Boolean.TRUE);
```

But nothing helped me.

output xml like below

```
<Signature
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="WmEbXML-Signature-54cl6h00gi08isbf003ient2">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <Reference URI="">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
                                <XPath>not(ancestor-or-self::eb:TraceHeaderList or ancestor-or-self::eb:Via)</XPath>
                            </Transform>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="cid:aseXML">
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>+VwuE6JsSHeCXWC+DPxgjVeJW3s=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>aC8ktJUPln/upPXzh1bKOwixJR7MzCPR/fti/Y51hHBGXTH+9YYbfjDYPDoujUwBMPFYiYvW8mwy&#13;
SK8hw033Jo2FsG5MzTnLkDWL/iLA48RBADeP0RLh5a4w2bm/6afxBejKPyZsMQI6xZVjYfYhHN66&#13;
o873Ut66NA67QYrO3bQ3Pmf6OQZYrghDfYdDcR+UMkBclzUnl7hLe2zk2FUg8ciUghe+mAQTrodr&#13;
qfZkGRUuZuk4ApoYuHfTuCVVPuFumnK0cxGpZ+t8F+veuRi8fDmDuj00xtekos0RvveHkXDJV86f&#13;
5e3qbF5dFoCT2wAPrI176yZmM2Tj3kU1zxqnDQ==</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <KeyValue>
                        <RSAKeyValue>
                            <Modulus>tEwpS7E66OGOtjRmxF/n2WhRtSG4fX1plZWOMC6muIQKRmNeZ4R1rIhWN9/ApIvnU2s3ydV6EuYx&#13;
Xwgg6Dj+rFqLyD4ad5kpe4iValJw6+iUgNsdPXeX4nyzSyjrYwqXBWcJ1PySuVjN4fGI20M/9UBN&#13;
6p35N/7SQhkrx9Hrj+y/sIZj33SDLrqw79HeoTbah1aL8V4Ah02tYQi20qRAsyM1dz3czuzCdvA2&#13;
flQFlWJsX0NEFFyDfbOEQk6ZbeWYdbSHxYvEjWy0A0EQ2bfBog0A/ulVCMY8VFHVohcVi6+jwmHq&#13;
6rFezTKnDeCaY9fL9/1n07CjEOzDvYJp5FlfSw==</Modulus>
                            <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
                        </RSAKeyValue>
                    </KeyValue>
                    <X509Data>
                        <X509SubjectName>XXX</X509SubjectName>
                        <X509Certificate>MIIFAzCCA+ugAwIBAgIQD8BrY2+s1N8STrkTMhU63zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBcMQswCQYDVQQG&#13;
EwJBVTEyMDAGA1UEChMpQXVzdHJhbGlhbiBFbmVyZ3kgTWFya2V0IE9wZXJhdG9yIExpbWl0ZWQx&#13;
GTAXBgNVBAMTEEFFTU8tSUNBLVRFU1QgRzEwHhcNMjMwMjE3MDAwMDAwWhcNMjYwMjE1MjM1OTU5&#13;
WjBbMQswCQYDVQQGEwJBVTERMA8GA1UECBMIVmljdG9yaWExEjAQBgNVBAcTCU1lbGJvdXJuZTEN&#13;
MAsGA1UEChMEQUVNTzEWMBQGA1UEAxMNU1VNTzItUHJlUHJvZDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAD&#13;
ggEPADCCAQoCggEBALRMKUuxOujhjrY0ZsRf59loUbUhuH19aZWVjjAupriECkZjXmeEdayIVjff&#13;
wKSL51NrN8nVehLmMV8IIOg4/qxai8g+GneZKXuIlWpScOvolIDbHT13l+J8s0so62MKlwVnCdT8&#13;
krlYzeHxiNtDP/VATeqd+Tf+0kIZK8fR64/sv7CGY990gy66sO/R3qE22odWi/FeAIdNrWEIttKk&#13;
QLMjNXc93M7swnbwNn5UBZVibF9DRBRcg32zhEJOmW3lmHW0h8WLxI1stANBENm3waINAP7pVQjG&#13;
PFRR1aIXFYuvo8Jh6uqxXs0ypw3gmmPXy/f9Z9OwoxDsw72CaeRZX0sCAwEAAaOCAcAwggG8MB8G&#13;
A1UdIwQYMBaAFLObeJREzHBITOulhDEDmNo2+ssEMB0GA1UdDgQWBBTYcw2iSBrmnKmkVG6hk2Jv&#13;
CVaOUzAYBgNVHREEETAPgg1TVU1PMi1QcmVQcm9kMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIFoDAdBgNVHSUEFjAU&#13;
BggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIwbQYDVR0fBGYwZDAwoC6gLIYqaHR0cDovL2NybDMuZGlnaWNl&#13;
cnQuY29tL0FFTU9JQ0FURVNURzEuY3JsMDCgLqAshipodHRwOi8vY3JsNC5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20v&#13;
QUVNT0lDQVRFU1RHMS5jcmwwQQYDVR0gBDowODA2BglghkgBhv1sAQEwKTAnBggrBgEFBQcCARYb&#13;
aHR0cDovL3d3dy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vQ1BTMHEGCCsGAQUFBwEBBGUwYzAkBggrBgEFBQcwAYYY&#13;
aHR0cDovL29jc3AuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMDsGCCsGAQUFBzAChi9odHRwOi8vY2FjZXJ0cy5kaWdp&#13;
Y2VydC5jb20vQUVNTy1JQ0EtVEVTVEcxLmNydDAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA&#13;
A4IBAQCrrec8+7laWuMzxvmws/80dtdVKmwTTF/qXFy3k3ONDNqcfQteXjKxH83VFxi9rgKSt07H&#13;
G2HWzUnOzK4WSJ4Lwr/Af01Ycxy5zblSzfl/9A0yjgyX9rxFnRYtLYr8EqMXt18N1jdd+YH9L0P8&#13;
j+SKfdzm5C1tLTlWV2fKppaE2xjmYw3Bj4g8xG+bhaNR/sFXzp2NApovBjdsfh2BjBw1gXDdSKjh&#13;
8OE2/zEW7RcilwjDw8+8vJAEs1XQnc9zU1OiheWSdAjPXhxTtlGmcwKBqo8Gi75rTd2wxk747oIi&#13;
SKBjCVsLgdKu12RZGDmvH4vr3a/9P6VkyrHVuM5DGaFC</X509Certificate>
                    </X509Data>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the code block below.

```
static {
    System.setProperty("com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.ignoreLineBreaks", "true");
}
```